# adding new item in indexed property of struts

Tags: java, jsp, struts, indexed-properties

here is what i want to do:
I have an actionForm with an indexed property(a list of districts), I have managed to show and bind all items to form the list districts.

I want to have a jsp page that allow user to add and delete item in that list. The problem is that struts use for example districts[0], districts[1] to bind each item in the list, when i want new item to be added or deleted, does this mean i need to append new 'input' tag with name='districts[last_index]' at the end of the list using javascript for addition and remove input tags for the corresponding index for deletion? is there alternative for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the way it works. I have tried managing parameters like this and has worked fine. And, for the deletion, you need not re-index the items. You just need to manage the last_index. For your information:

If the list contains objects with nested property, you need to implement this. Otherwise, you can just get the items in the list with the listname specified.

E.g.:

For `List<Integer> integerInputs;`, `&integerInputs=1&integerInputs=230&integerInputs=332` will work.

For

```
class MyObj {
      String name;
      int id;
      .
      .
      Getters and Setters
      .
      .
}

List<MyObj> myObjList;
```

The url to populate the list would be something like `&myObjList[0].id=12&myObjList[0].name=testName1&myObjList[1].id=122&myObjList[1].name=testNameOnly`